# How do we hide private class when using it in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, inheritance, class-cluster, private-class

## Question

How do we hide private class when using it in Objective-C?

For example, as described below 
`PrivateFilter` is the class I want to hide.
`CustomFilter` is the class I make, which is open.
`GPUImageFilter` is the class public on Github, which is open, too.
And `CustomFilter` actully wraps the functionallity of `PrivateFilter`.

```
@interface CustomFilter : GPUImageFilter
@end

@interface PrivateFilter : GPUImageFilter
@end
```

## Possible Solutions

So there are two solutions:

### Solution 1: Class cluster

Have a look at the example `A Composite Object: An Example` in the [Apple document](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ClassClusters/ClassClusters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH4).
I followed the steps and make the following code.

```
// CustomFilter.h
@interface CustomFilter : GPUImageFilter
@end

// CustomFilter.m
@interface CustomFilter()
@property (nonatomic, strong) PrivateFilter *privateFilter;
@end

@implementation CustomFilter
- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _privateFilter = [[PrivateFilter alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

// and then override the most of GPUImageFilter functions...
@end
```

But somehow it doesn't work, so I try the solution 2.

### Solution 2: Init with PrivateFilter

```
// CustomFilter.h
@interface CustomFilter : GPUImageFilter
@end

// CustomFilter.m
@implementation CustomFilter
- (CustomFilter *)init
{
    self = (CustomFilter *)[[PrivateFilter alloc] init];
    return self;
}

@end
```

This works, but it's very strange to use `alloc` in `init`.
So I try the solution 3.

### Solution 3: factory class method

```
// CustomFilter.h
@interface CustomFilter : GPUImageFilter
+ (CustomFilter *)filter;
@end

// CustomFilter.m
@implementation CustomFilter
+ (CustomFilter *)filter
{
    CustomFilter *filter = (CustomFilter *)[[PrivateFilter alloc] init];
    return filter;
}

@end
```

This works, but it could not be inherited, just like class cluster.

### Repeat Question

SO which is the best solution? Or is there other some good solutions?

Comment: The first one should work I think, for inherited then you can forward all the implementation to the private property, would need to rewrite every function though

Answer (score 0):

I think you need protocol, instead of `CustomFilter` with factory approach. If you need some `GPUImageFilter` subclass you can make `GPUImageFilter<CustomFilter>`

```
//CustomFilter.h
@protocol CustomFilter

...

@end

typedef GPUImageFilter<CustomFilter> CustomFilter;

//PrivateFilter.h
#import "CustomFilter.h"
@interface PrivateFitler: CustomFilter
...
@end

//GPUImageFilter+CustomFilter.h
@interface GPUImageFilter(CustomFilter)

+ (CustomFilter *)filter;

@end

//GPUImageFilter+CustomFilter.m
#import "PrivateFilter.h"

@implementation GPUImageFilter(CustomFilter)

+ (CustomFilter *)filter
{
    return [[PrivateFilter alloc] init;
}
@end
```

With such approach Xcode even give you warnings if you forget to implement some methods.

Comment: For now, I can not let PrivateFitler inherits CustomFilter, because `PrivateFitler` is a third party library. And for `GPUImageFilter<CustomFilter>` I think maybe `GPUImageFilter<CustomFilterProtol>` is a better naming? This is a good approach to get the warnings from Xcode, though, thanks!

Comment: @allenlinli you should start from that `PrivateFitler` is class from third party library. You should just create protocol and return it from yours fabric.